# Clicking ID in Internet Explorer VBA does not register anything?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

An HTML ID that I am trying to click does not error out, but the click does not register anything in the IE window?

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="bt_lstcl_card btcc btcNoImg" id="rqAnswerOption0" data- 
 serpquery="/searchq=Beetlejuice+released&amp;filters=BTQI%3A%220%22+BTCI%3A%220%22+ShowTimesTaskPaneTrigger%3A%22false%22&amp;skipopalnative=true&amp;rnoreward=1&amp;FORM=ML151V" iscorrectoption="True" tabindex="0">
```

I have tried the following:

```
ie.Document.getElementById("rqAnswerOption0").Click
```

The above does not error out, but does not register anything in the IE window. So then I tried a FireEvent code:

```
Set element = ie.Document.getElementById("rqAnswerOption0")
     element.FireEvent ("onkeyup")
```

This also did not register anything. If I simply try to get the Text from the ID, that works:

```
set p = ie.Document.getElementById("rqAnswerOption0")
MsgBox p.innerText
```

I'm confused as to why I can get the text for the ID, but nothing registers when I try to click.

[image]

Comment: I think because it is just a HTML DIV. It is not a button or any other control which has click or any other event. you can fetch the contents of an element using its ID so it is working. you can try to check whether any JS function get called when you try to click the DIV manually. Than you can try to call it from your VBA code or try to submit the form of that HTML page may help to register the data.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: @QHarr The link is here, I'm not sure if everyone would be able to access: https://www.bing.com/search?q=Father%27s%20Day%202019&rnoreward=1&mkt=EN-US&FORM=ML12JG&skipopalnative=true&rqpiodemo=1&filters=BTEPOKey:%22REWARDSQUIZ_MSR_ThursdayBonusQuiz_20190613%22%20BTROID:%22Gamification_DailySet_20190613_Child2%22%20BTROEC:%220%22%20BTROMC:%2230%22

Comment: Can you inform us where is rqAnswerOption0 HTML control on that bing page? I try to find it and I got 1 instance of that text which is in a JS code. Other than that I did not get any other instance of rqAnswerOption0.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I added a picture of rqAnswerOption1. 0 should be the same thing. I'm not sure if what I provided is what you were looking for though?

Comment: I can see those DIv in your image but when I visit the link I did not see any those kind of Div's. For testing purpose, can you try to click the div using sendkeys to check whether it is working or not?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Sorry for the delayed response. I didn't try using SendKeys, but I did navigate to the site and tried to manually use the keyboard to hit enter on one of the answer options and nothing would register. I'm not very familiar with JS or anything like that, so I'm not sure if this means it's something that VBA couldn't handle?

Comment: Do you mean when you try to perform the steps manually and nothing happened? Try to use mouse click may help to trigger some event and similar you can try from your VBA code may help to solve the issue.